# Issues with os.popen and scutil

Tags: python, macos, shell, unix, networking

I am in need of information from `scutil` command. When I run `scutil -d -r xyz.com` on terminal. I can see few lines of output.
But when I do `scutil -d -r xyz.com > file.txt`, then only last line of command output something like `flags = 0x00000002 (Reachable)` can be seen in the file.

I am running this command from python and I need entire conents of this command.
The way I am running in python is:

```
import os

output = os.popen('scutil -r -d yahoo.com').read()
print output
```

Output for this is:

> flags = 0x00000002 (Reachable)

But I need all output of the command here too. Please let me know if there is any work around for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`scutil` print out information to `stderr` try using `&> file.txt` instead of `> file.txt`

in python try using:

```
import commands 
print commands.getstatusoutput("scutil -d -r xyz.com")
```

Comment: `commands` has been deprecated... it's probably not a good idea to use it for an answer. You could probably use `subprocess.check_output("scutil -d -r xyz.com", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)` to the same effect.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for sharing this. I was trying
    subprocess.Popen(['scutil','-d',' -r',domain],shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

But the thing suggested by you works like charm. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1424975 I through that in as an answer so there's something to point to besides our thread in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`os.popen` [is deprecated since 2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen)
The docs provide a primer on replacing `os.popen` using the `subprocess` module:
http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-popen-os-popen2-os-popen3

Example applied to your code:

```
import subprocess
my_process = subprocess.Popen('scutil -r -d yahoo.com', 
                              shell=True,
                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = my_process.communicate()
print out
print err
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `subprocess.check_output("scutil -d -r xyz.com", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("scutil -d -r xyz.com", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
print(output)
```

There's two things going on with that `check_output` command that you should be aware of:

1. `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` pipes the error output stream to standard out
2. `shell=True` executes the command through the shell. This gives you access to the same environment that the shell process is running in.